# Create a launcher activity which displays over the current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

The `Activity` of my Launcher is a floating window with transparent background and I want it to display in front of all other `Activities` once the user hits the home button.

But Android always hides the other `Activities` and the floating window is only in front of the wallpaper :(

Is there a way to keep the current `Activity` in background when the Home Screen starts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want someting like that, but you can use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to display a layout over all other Activitys:

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    400,
                    400,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
wlp.windowAnimations = 0;
wm.addView([your layout], wlp);
```

You need to grant permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: This is only a part of what I need. The main problem is that Android "hides" all `Activities` when you press the home button (the Launcher is not opened on top (like when you start a normal `Activity`)

Comment: Ah... you want to suspress the normal home button behaviour, sorry but i have no clue how to achief this. I think you're only able to override the BackPress, but not the Home button

Answer (score 0):

From whatever I understood, you need transparent Activity.
If yes then you can do following.

In your `styles,xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/trans</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toobar</item>
</style>
```

And the give Theme to activity which you want to be transparent in manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Search"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent.lol" >
</activity>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks but Android still hides the Activity in which the user pressed home... So I get a transparant Launcher `Activity` in front of "nothing"